# C++ 2D grid array, reading and inserting array values from file

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I have created a code which outputs my array into a 2 dimensional grid, something like x and y axis. Currently the code and the output:

Code:

```
char array[9][9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = '0';

    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    cout << i << "  ";
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        cout << array[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "   ";
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    cout << i << "  ";
cout << endl;
```

Output:

```
0  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
1  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
2  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
3  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
4  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
5  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
6  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
7  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
8  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O  O 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Now i have a file, inside filled with coordinates that i'm suppose to mark out. The problem is how do i mark out all the coordinates, say to put a '1' on all the coordinates marked, on the grid that i've done. Firstly, i have declared my ifstream and managed to read its contents. And now i'm stuck! *Any help would be appreciated.*

This is the file content:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[2, 7]
[2, 8]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[3, 7]
[3, 8]
[7, 7]
```

Comment: *Firstly, i have declared my ifstream and managed to read its contents.* Show your code.

Comment: try maybe `char dummy; int x, y; while (ifs >> dummy >> x >> dummy >> y >> dummy) array[x][y] = '1';`

Comment: Pay attention that your output isn't from 0-9, but from 0-8. To fix that make the size 10X10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifstream` has a constructor that gets your file's path. To read the chars from `.txt` file, all you have to do is to use `>>` operator from `ifstream` object, to your input variable. to check if you finish the reading, you can simply use `.eof` function, of the `ifstream` object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    ifstream file("/path/to/your/file/yourfile.txt"); // From the root directory (in linux)
    size_t size = 9; // Make this program to be more dynamically
    char array[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = '0';

        }
    }

    int x, y;
    char padding;

    while (!file.eof()) // While there is somthing more in the file
    {
        file >> padding >> x >> padding >> y >> padding;
        /*
          read char '[', then 'x'(number), then ',', then 'y'(number), and finally ']'
        */
        array[x][y] = '1'; // Place the mark
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i << "  ";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << i << "  ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```